# Proof of (MV Calculus) sum and product rules for differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Say we have that

1) If $s:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $s(x,y)=x+y$, then $$Ds(a,b)=s.$$

2) If $p:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $p(x,y)=xy$, then $$Dp(a,b)(x,y)=bx+ay.$$ Thus $p'(a,b)=(b,a)$.

This is Theorem 2.3 from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds. The following statement is Corollary 2.4. The notation is a bit hard to write down, so, is the proof fine?

Corollary: If $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable at $a$, then $$D(f+g)(a)=Df(a)+Dg(a)$$ $$D(f*g)(a)=g(a)Df(a)+f(a)Dg(a).$$ If, moreover, $g(a) \neq 0$, then $$D(f/g)(a)=\frac{g(a)Df(a)-f(a)Dg(a)}{[g(a)]^2}$$
Proof: If $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable at $a$, then we have $$D(f+g)(a)=D(s \circ (f,g))(a)=Ds(f(a),g(a)) \circ D(f,g)(a)=$$ $$Ds(f(a),g(a)) \circ (Df(a),Dg(a))=Df(a)+Dg(a),$$ and we also have $$D(f*g)(a)=D(p \circ (f,g))(a)=Dp(f(a),g(a)) \circ D(f,g)(a)=$$ $$Dp(f(a),g(a)) \circ (Df(a),Dg(a))=g(a)Df(a)+f(a)Dg(a);$$ if in addition $g(a) \neq 0$ and $h \circ g=1/g$, then we also obtain $$D(f/g)(a)=D[p \circ (f,1/g)](a)=Dp(f(a),(1/g)(a)) \circ D(f,1/g)(a)=$$ $$Dp(f(a),(1/g)(a)) \circ (Df(a),D(1/g)(a))=(1/g(a))Df(a)+f(a)D(h \circ g)(a)=$$ $$\frac{1}{g(a)}Df(a)+f(a)[Dh(g(a)) \circ Dg(a)]=\frac{1}{g(a)}Df(a)+f(a)\frac{-1}{[g(a)]^2}Dg(a)=$$ $$\frac{g(a)Df(a)-f(a)Dg(a)}{[g(a)]^2}.$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look great!  I agree the notation kind of sucks, but this is the way of the world.

It might help you (notationally) to write all of these derivatives as matrices in some small dimensional cases, just to confirm to yourself that it all makes sense.

Note that even the case of $f,g:\mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^1$ are covered by these proofs.  In other words, the sum, product, and quotient rules from single variable calculus can be seen as an application of the multivariable chain rule, together with the computation of the derivative of the "sum", "product", and "quotient" maps from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^1$